# What is the use of "Disallow: /sitepanel/ and Disallow: /cgi-bin/"?

Tags: web-crawler, seo, robots.txt, google-crawlers

I've seen some websites using "Disallow: /sitepanel/ OR Disallow: /cgi-bin/" in their robots.txt file. I understand that we use "Disallow:" to stop search engine crawlers from crawling a particular webpage or directory but I am not getting the idea that why we need to disallow "/cgi-bin/ or /sitepanel" directory?
Any help in this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

as you said, search engines will stop crawling this pages.

There are 2 benfits by doing that:

1. This pages will never appear in the search results. You don't want users to access them easily.
2. Search engines can focus on your important pages and not waste the crawl budget for nothing.